# CSS & Regex, switching values of padding or margin property

Tags: php, css, regex, margin, padding

I have CSS code where I want to find Padding -or- Margin Properties
(where it has 4 values) and to switch the left value with right value:
e.g. `padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px;` 
- to be like this -
`padding: 1px 4px 3px 2px;`
How can I achieve this with regex & PHP? :-)

Comment: Do you want this to happen in your PHP code or at your Javascript? 
I don't see way you have to make such change inside a php code..

Comment: @Svetlio I want to make PHP code that search inside the CSS file and do switching & replacing then rewriting the CSS with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace(
    '/padding:\s*?(\d*px)\s*(\d*px)\s*(\d*px)\s*(\d*px)\s*?;/i',
    'padding: $1 $4 $3 $2;',
    $css
);
```

### Explanation

`\s` matches a space

`\d` matches a digit

`\d*px` will match any digits followed by a 'px'

Comment: There could be multiple spaces between attributes. Downvote fight?

Comment: The rule might not be followed by a semicolon

Comment: This matches invalid things like `padding:1px2px3px4px;`

Comment: @Eric true that, made adjustments

Comment: I changed it to `'/padding:\s*?(\d*p?x?)\s*(\d*p?x?)\s*(\d*p?x?)\s*(\d*p?x?)\s*?/i'` in order for it to match margin: 0 5px 0 10px