# finding CSS margins and paddings only with 4 parameters by regex

Tags: php, css, regex

I'm going to find all the paddings and margins that **only** have 4 parameters by **regular expression**, so created a regexp pattern like this:

```
(margin|padding)[ ]*:([ ]*((-*\d+(px|em|%|cm|in|pc|pt|mm|ex)?|auto|inherit)[ ]*)(!important)*){4};
```

But I have found one problem! It also passes this:

```
margin: 1px 11px 4px;
```

But I don't know how should solve this problem, also I don't know it has other problems or is it optimized?
Please edit this if possible or offer a new pattern.
Thanks

Comment: my question is **almost** like this topic: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191473/css-regex-switching-values-of-padding-or-margin-property?rq=1). but it is not answered yet!

Comment: no, it doesn't presently ends with }. but it is possible.

Comment: I deleted my comment, sorry. I thought there was a problem with initial and/or terminal space but that's not the case. Please see my answer instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the `?` after unit:

```
(margin|padding)[ ]*:([ ]*((-*\d+(px|em|%|cm|in|pc|pt|mm|ex)|auto|inherit)[ ]*)(!important)*){4};
```

Otherwise your regex matches any value with 4 digits at least, whether or not there are units or space in-between.

Then following examples won't match anymore (they did with your regex):

```
padding: 1111px;
padding: 444px 6px;
padding: 4px 356px;
padding: 44px 36px;
padding: 4px 11px 3px;
padding: 4px 1px 3px 56px;

padding: auto;
padding: 4443px auto;
padding: auto 22356px;
padding: auto 36px 89em;
padding: 42px 11px auto;
padding: 4px auto 3px 56px;
```

Tested on https://regexr.com/418b9

EDIT: there are new units like `vh` or `vw`. And `-prefix-calc(10% - 6px)`. If you're analysing legacy code, no prob ^^ but if you're searching into the wild wild web you may find a few occurences of that.

Comment: but **some times** phrases have unit. for example:`padding: auto 0 4px 2em;`

Comment: That part wasn't changed, should work as it did for you. I'll edit examples with some auto keywords, seems fine.

Comment: yes but it doesn't work when there is only digit without any unit: `padding: 4px auto **3** 56px;`

Comment: i solved the problem by separating digits with unit an digits without unit: `(margin|padding)[ ]*:([ ]*((-*\d+(px|em|%|cm|in|pc|pt|mm|ex)|-*\d+|auto|inherit)[ ]*)(!important)*){4};`

Comment: This isn't a valid value for a padding, you shouldn't match it

Comment: You could also extend it a little further by adding in 'border-width': (margin|padding|border-width)[ ]*:([ ]*((-*\d+(px|em|%|cm|in|pc|pt|mm|ex)|-*\d+|auto|inherit)[ ]*)(!important)*){4};

Comment: Its taking only values and last digit of integer; Not working

Comment: @AjeetKumar [It matches what is expected](https://regexr.com/418b9) (4-parameters values) and only that. Then yes, what is captured isn't OK if you want to replace it. As I don't know how to replace when an `{a,b}` quantifier is present, [expanding it](https://regexr.com/4189s) works but there's certainly a better solution or at least more _elegant_.